# IDLE-like indenting for Python in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hi I am using Notepad++ v7.5 64 bit with PC and running Windows 10

I am a beginner Python developer and recently made the switch from notepad to notepad++ after losing a lot of data by automatic update.  Nice so far, but one thing I would like to have in notepad++ is the idle like auto tab feature. For instance, you can press enter after defining a function or writing an if statement and it automatically indents the next line.

I looked at the other answers, but they seem to be outdated as simply selecting autotab doesn't work.  In addition, because I am running the 64 bit version of Notepad++, installing a plugin such as "Python indent" doesn't work either.

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this is a question on np++ , but check out `sublime text 3` or `atom` , far superior and better

Comment: thanks I thought that you had to pay for both, but have been playing around with atom and it seems to fit this use case very nicely

Comment: your welcome, have fun coding :)